# Inefficient School-Work Code; Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Tags: c, runtime-error

So I've been writing a program for my school C class (it isn't pretty, it isn't efficient, but It needs to work.) The assignment was to create a simplified GPS tracker simulation program that takes unknown movement coordinates (x,y), and maps these coordinates onto 2 different lines (roads) by creating a point on whichever line is closest to the input coordinates.The point created on the line is the line's nearest point to the input coordinates.

The program is supposed to track all the times direction is changed and is also supposed to track the total distance "traveled" *along the road(s)*. 
I am stuck on the last part of the assignment which asks me to implement direction changing (going from one road to another) -- note that the distance of a road change is the distance to the roads' intersection and the distance traveled after the turn.

The problem I'm having is that my Total_distance variable is not being updated, and I am fairly certain it's because my line 146 conditional branch is not being taken.

Main is not allowed to be modified.

I don't really have a clue what to do and I'm hoping someone may be able to spot a logical problem that I can't seem to find. I need to figure out the problem before I can fix it. I appreciate any assistance that can be provided.

Also, main() is not allowed to be modified.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Gobal Variables */
double M1; // Road 1 slope
double B1; // Road 1 y-intercept
double M2; // Road 2 slope
double B2; // Road 2 y-intercept

#ifndef SECRET_TESTS
double M1=-1.0, B1=0; // Road 1 slope and intercept
double M2=1.0, B2=0;  // Road 2 slope and intercept
#else 
// This allows the program to be tested easily with different roads
double M1=SECRET_M1, B1=SECRET_B1;
double M2=SECRET_M2, B2=SECRET_B2;
#endif

int Line=1, First_line=1;
int Changed_direction=0;
double Total_distance=0;

/* -----------------------*/


/* Function Declarations */
void track(double x, double y);
double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
double nearest_point_on_line(int line, double x, double y);
double distance_to_line(int line, double x, double y);
int closest_line(int line, double x, double y);
/* -----------------------*/



int main() {

  double x, y;
  int ret;

  do {
    // get x,y coordinate from stdin
    ret = scanf("%lf%lf",&x,&y); // ret = number of inputs successfully recieved

    if (ret==2)
      {
    // call into the tracking algorithm
    track(x,y);
      }

    // if we didn't get two doubles, time to quit
  } while(ret==2);

  // print out final results
  printf("Total distance = %.2lf\n",Total_distance);
  printf("# of changes in direction = %d\n",Changed_direction);
  printf("First Road = %d, Last Road = %d\n",First_line,Line);

  return 0;
}

void track(double x, double y){
    static int count = 1; // global variable; stores the total number of times the track function has been called
    static double Prior_x =0.0; // global variable; storing previous x road coordinate
    static double Prior_y = 0.0; // global variable; storing previous y road coordinate
    static double Prior_delta = 0.0; // sign of previous (x-Prior_x)
    static int Prior_Road = 0;
    double Current_delta = 0.0; // sign of previous (x-Prior_x)
    double Current_Road_M = 0.0;
    double Current_Road_B = 0.0;
    double Prior_Road_M = 0.0;
    double Prior_Road_B = 0.0;

    //CONDITIONALS FOR FIRST TIME TRACKING

    //printf("DEBUG: Raw input to Track. x: %lf, y: %lf\n", x, y);  
    if (count == 1){
        //printf("DEBUG: Track is running for the first time.\n");      
        switch (Line)                           //Set appropriate slope and y-intercept for road line
        {
        case 1:                         
            Current_Road_M = M1;
            Current_Road_B = B1;
            break;
        case 2:
            Current_Road_M = M2;
            Current_Road_B = B2;
            break;
        }
        //printf("DEBUG: Getting slope and y-intercept of Line.\nDEBUG: Line: %d, Current_Road_M: %lf, Current_Road_B: %lf\n", Line, Current_Road_M, Current_Road_B);
        First_line = Line = closest_line(Line, x, y);
        //printf("DEBUG: D(Prior_Road != Line)etermining true first line. First_line: %d\n", First_line);
        switch (Line)                           //Recalculate appropriate slope and y-intercept for road line
        {
        case 1:                         
            Current_Road_M = M1;
            Current_Road_B = B1;
            break;
        case 2:
            Current_Road_M = M2;
            Current_Road_B = B2;
            break;
        }
        //CONVERT INPUT COORDINATES INTO A ROAD POINT
        x = nearest_point_on_line(Line, x, y);              //get road x-coordinate
        y = x * Current_Road_M + Current_Road_B;            //calculate road y-coordinate   
    }
    else{
        Line = closest_line(Line,x,y);
        switch (Line)                           //Set appropriate slope and y-intercept for road line
        {
        case 1:                         
            Current_Road_M = M1;
            Current_Road_B = B1;
            break;
        case 2:
            Current_Road_M = M2;
            Current_Road_B = B2;
            break;
        }   

        //CONVERT INPUT COORDINATES INTO A ROAD POINT
        x = nearest_point_on_line(Line, x, y);              //get road x-coordinate
        y = x * Current_Road_M + Current_Road_B;            //calculate road y-coordinate   

        //ADD DISTANCE IF NO ROAD CHANGE (Distance for a road change is done below)
        if (Prior_Road == Line){
            Total_distance += distance(Prior_x, Prior_y, x, y);     //calculate distance between new position and old position; add calculated distance to total distance
        }
        //printf("DEBUG:Track is running.\n");      
        //printf("DEBUG: Prior_x: %lf, Prior_y: %lf, x: %lf, y: %lf\n", Prior_x, Prior_y, x, y);

        //DEFINE CURRENT_DELTA
        if ((x - Prior_x) < 0){
                Current_delta = -1;
            }
        else {
                if ((x - Prior_x) > 0){
                    Current_delta = 1;
                }
        }

        //DEFINE ROAD AND DIRECTION CHANGES
        if (count >= 3){
            if (((Current_delta != Prior_delta) && (Current_delta !=0) && (Prior_delta != 0)) || (Prior_Road == Line)){
                Changed_direction++;
                //IF ROAD CHANGE
                if (Prior_Road != Line){
                    //GET PRIOR_ROAD VALUES
                    switch (Prior_Road)         //Set appropriate slope and y-intercept for road line
                    {
                        case 1:                         
                            Prior_Road_M = M1;
                            Prior_Road_B = B1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Prior_Road_M = M2;
                            Prior_Road_B = B2;
                            break;
                    }   
                    //printf("DEBUG: Prior_Road: %d, Prior_Road_M: %lf, Prior_Road_B: %lf\n", Prior_Road, Prior_Road_M, Prior_Road_B ); 
                    //CALCULATE INTERSECTION
                    double x_intersect = (Prior_Road_B - Current_Road_B) / (Current_Road_M - Prior_Road_M);
                    double y_intersect = (x_intersect * Current_Road_M) + Current_Road_B;

                    //CALCULATE DISTANCE TO ADD
                    Total_distance += distance(Prior_x, Prior_y, x_intersect, y_intersect);
                    Total_distance += distance(x_intersect, y_intersect, x, y);

                }

            }
        }   
    }
    Prior_Road = Line;
    Prior_delta = Current_delta;
    Prior_x = x;
    Prior_y = y;
    count++;
    //DEBUG:printf("Track is running for the first time.\n");

return;}

double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    double delta_x = x2 - x1;                   //calcuate change in the x position
    double delta_y = y2 - y1;                   //calcuate change in the y position
    double distance = sqrt(pow(delta_x,2) + pow(delta_y,2));    //pythagorean theorem to determine distance between two points
return distance;}

double nearest_point_on_line(int line, double x, double y){
    //Define a test line containing the input point and
    //find the intersection of the test line and the road   
    double M_test = 0.00;
    double B_test = 0.00;
    double M_line = 0.00;   //holds slope of current road line
    double B_line = 0.00;   //holds y-intercept of current road line

    switch (line)                           //For line #)
        {
        case 1:                         
            M_line = M1;
            B_line = B1;
            break;
        case 2:
            M_line = M2;
            B_line = B2;
            break;
        }
    M_test= -1/M_line;
    B_test = -((M_test * x) - y);
    x = (B_test - B_line)/(M_line - M_test);
    return x;
}

double distance_to_line(int line, double x, double y){
    double x_line = 0.0;
    double y_line = 0.0;
    double M_line = 0.00;   //holds slope of current road line
    double B_line = 0.00;   //holds y-intercept of current road line
    switch (line)                           //For line #)
        {
        case 1:                         
            M_line = M1;
            B_line = B1;
            break;
        case 2:
            M_line = M2;
            B_line = B2;
            break;
        }
    x_line = nearest_point_on_line(line, x, y);
    y_line = x_line * M_line + B_line;
    return distance(x_line, y_line, x, y);
}

int closest_line(int line, double x, double y){ 
    //Compare the distance between the point and each line, return the value of the closest line;
    if (distance_to_line(1,x,y) < distance_to_line(2,x,y)){     
        //printf("DEBUG: closest_line returned 1\n");       
        return 1;
    }                       
    else if (distance_to_line(2,x,y) < distance_to_line(1,x,y)){
        //printf("DEBUG: closest_line returned 2\n");   
        return 2;   
    }
    //if the distances are equal, return the value of the current active line           
    else if (distance_to_line(2,x,y) == distance_to_line(1,x,y)){
        //printf("DEBUG: closest_line returned line\n");        
        return line;                        //value of current line
    }
    // if none of these cases hold, we have some serious issues...
    else return -1;                     //error
}
```

Comment: Nobody here is going to wade through 200 lines of code to find your error.  Learn how to debug.

Comment: Way to be supportive; I'm sorry for requesting another set of eyes after debugging for hours and only having another 24 hours to finish it.

Comment: Should be `char name[256]; ...  sscanf(line, "%255[^0123456789]%n %d %d "...`  256 vs 255.

Comment: Had and Error in my code, the condition should be (Prior_Road != Line)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm having is that my Total_distance variable is not being
>   updated, and I am fairly certain it's because my line 146 conditional
>   branch is not being taken

It's not very difficult to debug to know why. Since you doubt line 146 condition branch is not being taken, add some `printf` to see what happened.

It's fortunately your program can be compiled, I added printf after line:

`if (((Current_delta != Prior_delta) && (Current_delta !=0) && (Prior_delta != 0)) || (Prior_Road == Line))`

and then tested, it's enter!

So the real reason is the condition `if (Prior_Road != Line)` always true, is that you wanted? Because I found that the update lines are in the "always true condition" (**is that a brace issue?**), so Total_distance wasn't changed.

A little suggestion:
Debug as possible as you can, if simple like this, add some print can work, or step by step debug.

Comment: Why is that condition always true? If you look at the code, there are two places where Total_distance is added to; one condition where the Prior_Road is == Line and another where it is not equal (to handle the cases where there is no road change and one where there is a road change) -- EDIT: Noticed a typo in my code; still doesn't run, but the (Prior_Road == Line) should be (Prior_Road != Line)

Comment: I didn't do many tests, `Toatal_distance` was added on condition `Prior_Road is == Line` but wasn't added on another condition. So I suspect that.

Comment: Which line changed? `(Prior_Road == Line) ` line 146? if changed that, what do you mean "still doesn't run"? Prior_Road  still not changed?

Comment: BY still doesn't run I mean "Still doesn't run as intended." The extra || condition on line 146.